# Selected Index on Tab Bar not working on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I want to change the default selected view controller of a `UITabBar` / `UITabBarController` via `selectedIndex`.

I tried other solutions I saw in other threads, like changing it in the `AppDelegate` or in `ViewDidAppear` like this:

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTabBar()
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // this is the attempt to set the selected index that doesn't work 
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
    }

    func setupTabBar(){
        let vc1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainvc")
        let vc2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondvc")
        let vc3 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdvc")
        let FirstController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
        let SecondController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
        let ThirdController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc3)

        viewControllers = [FirstController, SecondController, ThirdController]
    }

}
```

Nothing worked so far, and it always shows the selected index = 0.

I set the tab bar view controller as the initial view controller in the `Main storyboard`. Should I be doing this in the `AppDelegate` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are saying that

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
```

so `self` refers to a `UITabBarController`, but you are setting the selected index of `tabBarController` *of* `self`:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

There are no tab bar controllers embedded in `self`. `self` itself *is* a tab bar controller! You can just set `self.selectedIndex`:

```
self.selectedIndex = 2
```

Also, you should do that in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidAppear`, because `viewDidAppear` can happen many times (every time some modal controller is dismissed for example). `viewDidLoad` will only be called once.